# Can virtual box be accessed while mac in sleep?

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine, sleep

I have a question regarding virtual box on my iMac, basically i've created a VM and i'm running there windows. I have made it accessible from internet etc etc, so it is ready, but i'm curious => if i start it headless and put my mac in sleep, can i still be able to access the virtual machine?

If not what other possibilities are there to access my VM anytime while not using my Mac (meaning it can be sleeping or what other stand should it be?) i suppose if Mac is shut down then it is definitely VM is not accessible, but yeah are there other ways? (exept keeping mac running 24/7)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible. Putting the VM host to sleep, will suspend all processes running on it, and thus the VM guest aswell...

Comment: what other possibilities are there then? maybe mac will jump up or wake up when i try to connect to VM? i don't know, are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the utilities which will wake up your Mac remotely. Once your Mac is awake, the VMs will be running.  Here is [one](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15779/wakeonlan) I found. (Disclaimer - I have not tried it).